# How to properly use migrations in lumen/laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I want to create several tables with FK on one table. 
Messing with foreign constraints which are fail on table creation on `up` method in migrations.

Should I use code like this

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('Pharmacy', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string("name");
    });

    if (Schema::hasTable('Drug')) {
        Schema::table('Drug', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('pharmacy_id')->references('id')->on('Pharmacy');
        });
    }

    if (Schema::hasTable('Address')) {
        Schema::table('Address', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('pharmacy_id')->references('id')->on('Pharmacy');
        });
    }


}
```

Or create new migration ?

Should I use new migrations on every table and foreign key, and one migration for creation of all tables is ok and another migration for adding FKs ?

Comment: Personally I don't do it this way with if (Schema::has...), because I can see no benefits in further execution of migrations if one fails, but your scenario may be different.

Comment: thanks for reply, so just to create new migration is okay ? basically to create tables with columns in first migration and then create another migration to add FK's ?

Comment: Both should work, it's only a question of how you like your code.